# No suitable method found for sort

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I run into a strange Java compiler issue

Here is the code

```
public int[] findRightInterval(int[][] intervals) {
  int n = intervals.length;
  int[] intIdx = new int[n];
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
     intIdx[i]=i;
  }
  Arrays.sort(intIdx, (a, b) -> (intervals[a][0]-intervals[b][0]));
  ...
}
```

The full error is

```
Line 8: error: no suitable method found for
sort(int[],(a,b)->(in[...]][0]))
        Arrays.sort(intIdx, (a, b) -> (intervals[a][0]-intervals[b][0]));
              ^
    method Arrays.<T#1>sort(T#1[],Comparator<? super T#1>) is not applicable
      (inference variable T#1 has incompatible bounds
        equality constraints: int
        lower bounds: Object)
    method Arrays.<T#2>sort(T#2[],int,int,Comparator<? super T#2>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T#2
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))   where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Object declared in method <T#1>sort(T#1[],Comparator<? super T#1>)
    T#2 extends Object declared in method <T#2>sort(T#2[],int,int,Comparator<? super T#2>)
```

On the other hand,
if I replace `Arrays.sort(intIdx, (a, b) -> (intervals[a][0]-intervals[b][0]));` with `Arrays.sort(intervals, (a, b) -> (a[0]-b[0]));` it works fine.

Wonder why the compiler throw that error?

Comment: Because there is no method in [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) to sort an `int[]` array with a comparator.

Comment: Look at the **documentation**, i.e. the [list of `sort` methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#i112) in the javadoc for `Arrays`, and you will see that there is no `sort` method taking an `int[]` that also takes a `Comparator`. The only `sort` method taking a `Comparator` is for an object array. You cannot sort primitive arrays with a `Comparator` using the built-in methods.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here? Looks like you want to sort the outer array *descending* by the value at index 0 in the inner array. So why not sort the outer array? It *is* an object, so you *can* sort it with a `Comparator`. E.g. `int[][] copy = intervals.clone(); Arrays.sort(copy, (a, b) -> Integer.compare(a[0], b[0]));`

Answer (score 1):

```
public static <T> void Arrays.sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)
```

You can't sort `int[]` array with comparator. Only `Integer[]`. So, your snippet could be rewritten with:

```
Arrays.sort(Arrays.stream(intIdx).boxed().toArray(), (a, b) -> intervals[a][0] - intervals[b][0]);
```

***P.S.** I reccoment you to use `Stream` for your example:*

```
intIdx = Arrays.stream(intIdx)
               .boxed()
               .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(a -> intervals[a][0]))
               .mapToInt(i -> i)
               .toArray();
```

Comment: If you're streaming to boxed `Integer` objects, it would make a lot more sense to sort in the stream using `sorted(...)`. *That* code surely makes no sense, because it is building and sorting an array and then immediately throwing the array away, so what's the point?

Comment: That new stream example doesn't do anything, since there is no terminal operation.

Comment: but `Arrays.sort(intervals, (a, b) -> (a[0]-b[0]))` works? it's also primitive type

Answer (score -1):

you can import the built-in class Collections;

and write this:Collections.sort(array);